# Incorporate another column to rhandsontable

Tags: r

I get the output as shown below . Can I add another column to rhandsontable and incorporate the features of `button` and `h1` as shown in the second picture (The picture is taken from excel for example. But it should be in rhandsontable only)

[image]

Required output

[image]

below is the code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(formattable)
```

```{r}
da <- data.frame(a = c("button","h1"))
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
tags$button("My header")
tags$h1("My header")
rhandsontable(da)
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

```

### Chart C

```{r}

```
````